# Identifying origin in convolution table

Tags: convolution

I am taking the convolution of $x(n)=\left\{2,1,-1,-2,3 \right\}$ with $n=0$ at the third position with $h(n)=\left\{1,2,0,3 \right\}$ with $n=0$ at the second position. The answer is $y(n)=\left\{2,5,1,-10, -10, -3, 6, -9 \right\}$ with the $n=0$ at the fourth position. I studied convolution more than a decade ago and I used a table to do the convolution sum as follows:

[image]

There used to be a simple rule to obtain the location of the $n=0$ position of the output $y(n)$ from the table itself or perhaps from $x(n)$ and $y(n)$. But alas I cannot remember it. Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a signal $x[n]$, guaranteed to be zero outside of the domain $N_1 \leq n \leq N_2$, and the signal $h[n]$ being zero outside of $M_1 \leq n \leq M_2$, then their convolution $y[n] = x[n] \star h[n]$ will be guaranteed to be zero outside of $N_1+M_1 \leq n \leq N_2 + M_2$.

Applying this to your case yields the following:
For the signal $x[n]$ with $n=0$ at third position the nonzero range is $-2 \leq n \leq 2$ and for $h[n]$ with $n=0$ at the second position the nonzero range is $-1 \leq n \leq 2$ which therefore yields the nonzero range of their convolution $y[n]$ is:
$$ -3 \leq n \leq 4 $$

which means that the $n=0$ for $y[n]$ is at the fourth position.

Comment: It's indeed correct of you to emphasise the phrase "nonzero range" in your answer.

Comment: @Fat32 you say non-zero range, but don't you mean domain? The domain defines the argument, but the range contains all possible value of the function

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure out the sample position, referring back to the convolution on sampled signals would be really helpful.

Considering our sampled input signal $x[n]$ and unit sample response $h[n]$, the convolution of those i.e. the sampled output signal is described as follows:

$$y[n] = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty}{x[m]h[n-m]}$$

The above convolution notation is similar to that is done in continuous time except for the evaluation process which is summation in discrete time analysis and is integral in continuous time analysis. The variable $m$ is utilised for the same purpose as $\tau$ is in the continuous time convolution formula.

One prominent thing to note in the discrete convolution formula is that the sample number interval is ${-\infty}<m<{\infty}$. This is the generalised sample number interval, both for causal and non-causal systems. In our case, as our unit sample response has sample magnitudes on the negative n-sample axis, the system of concern is non-causal and we can proceed with that sample number interval.

So, we have all the required things to go further. I’ve convolved those signals by hand and additionally, by using MATLAB for confirmation. The photo of the hand-written analysis is given below with a slightly different way of creating convolution table:

[image: The hand-written convolution]

Some crucial info about the table is given below which is going to play the key role at finalising the analysis:

- The variable $m$ is thought to be the main variable of the signals which means that the variable $m$ is doing exactly what the variable $n$ had been doing in those signals.
- The sampled input signal $x[n]$ have become $x[m]$ in light of the first statement in this info section.
- Likewise, the unit sample response $h[n]$ have become $h[m]$ and according to the convolution formula, for calculations, it is formed as $h[n-m]$ so that it is reversed on the m-sample axis and it will be shifted for different values of $n$ on the m-sample axis in the table. Indices of this unit sample response implies different shifted unit sample responses regardless of the value of $n$ i.e. those indices are not given according to the values of $n$.
- The values of $n$ on the right hand side of the table gives the amount of right shift that is done on the unit sample response.
- I've added zeroes for undefined sample number intervals.

The calculation of the convolution of the signals, parallel to the meaning of the discrete convolution formula, is just like this: Product of the corresponding values of sampled input signal $x[m]$ and the modified (reversed and shifted) unit sample response $h[n-m]$ is taken for each value of $n$ and they are summed up. The summation is placed into the sampled output signal vector $y[n]$ with regards to the value of $n$.

According to the info section above, as in the photograph, the sampled output signal becomes;

$$y[n] = [2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, -6, 9]$$

for;

$$n = -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$$

respectively.

And, as a result, the fourth sample from the left hand side of the output signal vector belongs to the sample number $n=0$.

In order to play safe, it is good to test the analysis via MATLAB. The MATLAB source code is given below:

```
x = [2, 1, -1, -2, 3]; % Sample magnitudes of x[n] sampled input signal.

h = [1, 2, 0, 3];      % Sample magnitudes of h[n] unit sample response.

y = conv(x, h)         % Sampled output signal that is the convolution of
                       % x[n] and h[n].
```

And the result of this source code is given as follows:

[image: The convolution on MATLAB]

The most important thing, even though the main point of the question is different than it, is that in the question the proposed answer of the sampled output signal is wrong. The correct answer is given above, both in terms of classical and software-based analysis.